# Check whether variable exists before checking value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This code is working for me, but I suspect there's a more ruby-ish way to do this.

```
<% this_score = this_student.scores.find_by(:assignment => team.assignment) %>
   <% if this_score && this_score.points == 100 %>
      <br/><small>(100%)</small>
   <% end %>
```

The first two lines embody my question. I do things this way to avoid the errors that occur if this_student.scores.find_by(:assignment => team.assignment) is nil. Isn't there some way to do this in one line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a “nil guard”. There are a few convenient patterns for this:

```
# safe navigation operator - if `nil_thing` is nil, `points` won't be called
nil_thing&.points

# the double ampersand check (what you've used)
if nil_thing && nil_thing.points == 100

# compound one-line conditional
do_stuff if nil_thing.points == 100 unless nil_thing.blank?
```

You can also avoid the situation a lot of the time:

```
if student.scores.where(points: 100, assignment: team.assignment).exists?
  do_stuff
end
```

Note that the way you're assembling this query makes it hard to avoid N+1 query issues.

I suspect that you don't have a proper relationship between Student and Assignment. I would rename `Score` to `StudentAssignment` and have a `score` attribute on it:

```
class Student
  has_many :student_assignments
  has_many :assignments, through: :student_assignments
end

class Assignment
  has_many :student_assignments
  has_many :students, through: :student_assignments
end
```

Then you can use basic eager loading and value-comparisons in Ruby:

```
Assignment.includes(student_assignments: :students).each do |assignment|
  puts "Scores for #{assignment.name}:"
  assignment.student_assignments.each do |sa| 
    puts "#{sa.student.name} scored #{sa.score}"
    puts "Congratulations to #{sa.student.name}" if sa.score >= 99
  end
end
```

You can do this from the other direction as well: loop through a student and show their assignments with scores.

If you have a setup where there's no possibility of connecting a Student to the Assignment many-to-many, you could setup a conditional association like `perfect_scores` that will let you eager load an otherwise arbitrary query, taking advantage of ActiveRecord relationship navigation to avoid N+1:

```
class Student
  has_many :scores
  has_many :perfect_scores, -> { where(score: 100) }, class_name: 'Score', inverse_of: :student

  def perfect_score_on_assignment?(assignment)
    if perfect_scores.loaded?
      # use cached data
      perfect_scores.any? { |score| score.assignment_id == assignment.id } 
    else 
      # use sql to determine
      perfect_scores.where(assignment: assignment).exists?
    end
  end
end

class Score
  belongs_to: :student
  belongs_to: :assignment
end

class Assignment
  has_many :scores
end

# Load up all of the students and eager load perfect scores
@students = Student.includes(perfect_scores: :assignment)
@assignments = Assignment.all

@assignment.each do |assignment|
  @students.each do |student|
    if student.perfect_score_on_assignment?(assignment)
      puts "#{student.name} scored 100%"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the helpful explanation along with your answer. I have one function that checks every assignment with every student, so it runs these lines a few thousand times. Which pattern would you suggest for best performance?

Comment: @JeffZivkovic Just updated with two loosely hypothetical examples of how to handle this depending on your situation.

Comment: Now that's going above and beyond! I'll try to adapt your example to my app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ruby's Safe Navigation Operator as explained [here](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/).

```
<% this_score = this_student.scores.find_by(:assignment => team.assignment) %>
   <% if this_score&.points == 100 %>
      <br/><small>(100%)</small>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use safe navigation operator `&.` in 2.3.

```
<% this_score = this_student.scores.find_by(:assignment => team.assignment) %>
   <small>(<%= this.student&.score || 0 %>%)</small>
<% end %>
```